# if..increment variable else..increment different variable

Tags: python

There must be a better/more efficient way to do this. I want to increment one variable if the first string matches, or the second variable if it matches the second string.

```
ifCount = 0
elseCount = 0
for x in dict:
    if x["bla"] == 'this':
        ifCount += 1
    elif x["bla"] == 'that':
        elseCount += 1
```

Comment: What don't you like about this approach? Why do you think it's "inefficient"? Did you try running the code? Was it unacceptably slow for your purposes?

Comment: `dict` is not a good choice for a variable name.

Comment: sorry dict isn't actually the name, I guess I should have called it aDict or something. Inefficient wasn't the correct word, I guess I meant it just seems like something that I should be able to do in fewer than 7 lines of code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

items = [
    {"bla": "this"},
    {"bla": "this"},
    {"bla": "that"},
    {"bla": "that"},
    {"bla": "that"},
    {"bla": "that"},
    {"bla": "this"},
    {"bla": "that"}
]

counter = Counter(map(itemgetter("bla"), items))

print(counter["this"])
print(counter["that"])
```

Output:

```
3
5
>>>
```

Comment: thanks I knew something like this had to exist

Answer (score 0):

In terms of efficiency, there's nothing wrong with your code. It's concise and iterates once. If you want to shorten it a bit, we can use `filter`.

```
ifCount = len(filter(lambda x: x['bla'] == 'this', dict))
elseCount = len(filter(lambda x: x['bla'] == 'this', dict))
```

It's shorter, but it's debatable whether it's more readable or less. This syntax may make sense in a larger codebase where the `lambda` is actually some frequently-used and well-known function, but in this isolated example, I'd argue the `for` loop is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The "obvious" way to handle this is with a dict to count the occurrences.  First, change the name of your existing iterable from `dict` to something usable, say `d` for now ...

Simply use a Counter object.

```
from collections import Counter
label_count = Counter(entry["bla"] for entry in d)
```

`label_count` now contains the counts of all `"bla"` entries in `d` -- specifically, your counts of `this` and `that`.  If you want only the two elements out of many, you can add a clause `if entry["bla"] in ["this", "that"]`.